# How to compare two TXT files before send it to SQL

Tags: c#, winforms, bulkinsert, text-files

I have to handle TXT dat files which coming from one embed device, My problem is in that device always sending all captured data but I want to take only difrences between two sending and do calculation on them. After calculation I  send it to SQL using bulkinsert  function. I want to extract data which is different according to first file I got from device. Lats say that device first time device send data like this in some.dat (ASCII) file

```
0000199991
0000199321
0000132913
0000232318
0000312898
```

On second calls to get data from device it is going to return all again (previous and next captured records) something like this

```
0000199991
0000199321
0000132913
0000232318
0000312898
9992129990
8782999022
2323423456
```

But this time I do want only to calculate and pass trough data added after first insert.
I am trying to make Win Forms app using C# and Visual Studio 2008

Comment: Thanks on all good answers, As I am here fighting with English grammar and drowse, I forgot to make mention of Sometime device get restarted and send only new data, also until now I loaded data to dataset not to sting, If I load file to sting will be heavy after that to convert it to dataset so I can send it to SQL.

Comment: Please show us your current code.

Comment: Regarding to show code, my hands are tied until morning when I came to office, forgive me on that , first thing in the morning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using LINQ:

```
string[] addedLines = File.ReadAllLines(secondPath)
                          .Except(File.ReadAllLines(firstPath))
                          .ToArray();
```

Note that this will be slow for large files.

For large files, replace `ReadAllLines` with the following method: (In .Net 4, you can use  [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) instead)

```
static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateLines(string path) {
    using(var reader = File.OpenText(path)) {
        string line;
        while(null != (line = reader.ReadLine())
            yield return line;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does 3 to 5 thousand records considering Large files

Comment: Perhaps; see whether it runs too slowly.

Comment: Yet for while I trying to implement Your first method, And it works well, only one thing that I do not understand is: When I am using Except in lambda expressions some how addedLines array is grouped by same records. Is there way to I avoid grouping data in new array and still to use Except, Thanx a lot

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to remember the filesize each time you receive the file, then when you get the new file you can immediately move the file pointer to the position in the file that corresponds to the end of the previous file and read from that point on.

Here is a rough outline of the idea

```
  long lastPosition = GetLastFilePositionFromDatabase();
  using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(...))
  {
    // Seek to the last position, this is zero the first time
    fs.Seek(lastFilePosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // Process your file from the current position
    ProcessFile(fs);

    // Once you reach the end of the file, save this position so 
    // for use with the next file
    SaveLastFilePositionToDatabase(fs.Position);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
string dataAddedAfterFirstInsert = secondString.SubString(firstString.Length, secondString.Length)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know now, toll tomorrow When I get back in office to try